# How to use JIRA REST client library?

Tags: java, maven, jira, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

I need to use JIRA REST client version 5.2.0 or higher. Cloud JIRA does not work with an earlier version of the client.

In my `pom.xml` file I have the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-app</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I building the project, I get an exception like this:

```
Failed to execute goal on project XXXXXXXXX: Could not resolve dependencies for project  XXXXXXXXXX:jar:XXXX: Failed to collect dependencies at com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:jar:5.2.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:jar:5.2.1: Could not find artifact com.atlassian.platform:platform:pom:3.1.7 in MY_REPO (http://XXXXXXXXXX/repository/maven-public) -
```

`com.atlassian.platform:platform:pom:3.1.7` is not listd at [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.atlassian.platform/platform). There are versions `3.1.12` and `3.1.17`, but not `3.1.7`. Someone told me that version `3.1.7` might have had a security-related bug and was therefore removed by Atlassian.

Both `jira-rest-java-client-app` and `jira-rest-java-client-core` are children of [jira-rest-java-client-parent](https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/com/atlassian/jira/jira-rest-java-client-parent/5.2.1/), which [uses](https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/com/atlassian/jira/jira-rest-java-client-parent/5.2.1/jira-rest-java-client-parent-5.2.1.pom) version `3.1.7` of the platform:

```
    <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
    <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-parent</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    [...]

    <properties>
        <platform.version>3.1.7</platform.version>

        [...]

    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.atlassian.platform</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
                <version>${platform.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
```

`5.2.1` seems to be the latest version of both [jira-rest-java-client-core](https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/com/atlassian/jira/jira-rest-java-client-core/) and [jira-rest-java-client-app](https://packages.atlassian.com/maven-public/com/atlassian/jira/jira-rest-java-client-app/).

How can I use the JIRA REST client (for programmatically creating issues in Cloud JIRA) when it uses a version of the library that is not available any more?

I tried to exclude the platform in the dependencies and to specify another version in depencency management sections. This did not help.

Comment: i am sorry i may be wrong in understanding your question.. but you can have the needed version in a private repo.. and have that added in your ~/.m2/settings as a <pluginRepository>
          <id>thirdParty</id>

Comment: @YatishKadam I don't want to use version `3.1.7` because I assume Atlassian removed it for a reason. If I use it, my system may have some security problem. I am asking how to fix the problem the right way (without using an outdated and presumably flawed version of the platform).

Comment: have you tried to update the pom files on JIRA REST client ? to use the latest version and see if that builds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a look at the repository

https://packages.atlassian.com/mvn/maven-external

from atlassian, you find the desired artifact `com.atlassian.platform:platform:pom:3.1.7`there. Since this repository seems to be from atlassian, I see no reason to believe that they recommend not to use the version.

This is also discussed in https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Jira-rest-java-client-core-5-1-and-fugue-2-7-0-breaks-build/qaq-p/1151091

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is absolutely correct. A concrete example on how to be able to get the artifacts from https://packages.atlassian.com, for anyone coming here looking for answers, would be to include a `repository` element for it in your pom, like so:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>atlassian-public</id>
        <url>https://packages.atlassian.com/maven/repository/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

**A WORD OF CAUTION, THOUGH: The jira-rest-java-client was created for use with Jira Server, not Jira Cloud**

Some months ago, Atlassian made changes to Jira Cloud which made it impossible to use the `jira-rest-java-client` (JRJC) for things such as searches in Jira Cloud. As far as I can tell they don't intend to make the JRJC library compatible with Jira Cloud anymore. Atlassian has provided an article on [how to generate a REST client for Jira Cloud](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-articles/Generating-a-REST-client-for-Jira-Cloud/ba-p/1307133), but as far as I know, they haven't created any Jira Cloud libraries similar to the JRJC.